# PostgreSQL not installed but showing in running process (ubuntu)

Tags: postgresql

Well I have removed PostgreSQL and PostgreSQL xc but some process are running with username postgre+.

When I use `sudo dpkg --purge postgres`, I am getting:

> dpkg: warning: ignoring request to remove postgres which isn't installed

And when I see running processes it shows

```
postgre+  1175  0.0  0.1 140044 10004 ?        S    20:07   0:00 /usr/bin/postgres --datanode -D /var/lib/postgres-xc/DN1
nobody    1202  0.0  0.0  35224  1544 ?        S    20:07   0:00 /usr/sbin/dnsmasq --no-resolv --keep-in-foreground --no-hosts --bind-interfaces --pid-
postgre+  1203  0.0  0.0 140044  2020 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                          
postgre+  1204  0.0  0.0 140044  1776 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: writer process                                
postgre+  1205  0.0  0.0 140044  1548 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                            
postgre+  1206  0.0  0.0 140764  2824 ?        Ss   20:07   0:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                   
postgre+  1207  0.0  0.0 108012  1580 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                       
postgre+  1262  0.0  0.1 140036  9984 ?        S    20:07   0:00 /usr/bin/postgres --datanode -D /var/lib/postgres-xc/DN2
root      1267  0.0  0.0      0     0 ?        S    20:07   0:00 [kauditd]
postgre+  1310  0.0  0.1 140032 10016 ?        S    20:07   0:00 /usr/bin/postgres --coordinator -D /var/lib/postgres-xc/CN
postgre+  1376  0.0  0.0 140036  2012 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                          
postgre+  1377  0.0  0.0 140036  1764 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: writer process                                
postgre+  1378  0.0  0.0 140036  1536 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                            
postgre+  1379  0.0  0.0 140756  2812 ?        Ss   20:07   0:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                   
postgre+  1380  0.0  0.0 108004  1568 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                       
postgre+  1412  0.0  0.0 140032  1536 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: pooler process                                  
postgre+  1414  0.0  0.0 140032  2012 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process                            
postgre+  1415  0.0  0.0 140032  1764 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: writer process                                  
postgre+  1416  0.0  0.0 140032  1536 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: wal writer process                              
postgre+  1417  0.0  0.0 143560  4900 ?        Ss   20:07   0:01 postgres: autovacuum launcher process                     
postgre+  1418  0.0  0.0 108000  1568 ?        Ss   20:07   0:00 postgres: stats collector process                         
postgre+  1457  0.0  0.0  83336  2200 ?        S    20:07   0:00 /usr/bin/gtm -D /var/lib/postgres-xc/GTM -l /var/log/postgres-xc/datanode.log
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously removing the package did not stop the running process before removing all files. Just `kill` the master process and it will go away:

```
kill 1175
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual master process was 1310.

I used

```
kill 1310
```

and all the processes were terminated.

Comment: This site is no forum, you should accept the answer krisku gave if it lead you to the solution, rather than posting that you agree.